# Stop page scroll animation when user touches page

Tags: jquery

Hi I found this code on the forum that partially does what I want, but I can't insert a new function.

That is to stop the scroll when the finger is put on the screen from the mobile.

```
$('html, body').animate(
  { scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() },
  12000,
  function() {
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 12000);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to "stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements".

Try adding this to your page:

```
$('html, body').on("touchend", function(e) {
  $(this).stop();
});
```